# Hypocrisy don't makes you / doesn't make you a human

Tags: negation, subject-verb-agreement, perfect-constructions

> Hypocrisy **don't makes** you a human.
>   Hypocrisy **doesn't make** you a human.

Which would be grammatically correct: *don't makes you* or *doesn't make you*?

Or perhaps it should be:

> Hypocrisy **would never make** you a human.

Comment: Welcome to ELU! May I ask what your native language is?

Comment: The correct version is "doesn't make": _Hypocrisy doesn't make you a human._ An alternative might be: _Hypocrisy could never make you a human_, but I'm with @FumbleFingers – I'm having trouble understanding what the sentence could possibly mean. If there was ever a trait that was unique to humans, it'd be hypocrisy (but I suppose that aspect of the sentence ought to be discussed at [philosophy.se]).

Answer (score 4):

The verb in a sentence may be a single lexical verb (a verb with distinct 'meaning') or a 'chain' of one or more auxiliary verbs ('helper' verbs) followed by the lexical verb.

However many verbs there are in the chain, only the *first* is inflected to agree with the subject of the sentence for tense, person and number. The other verbs in the chain are all "non-finite" forms: an infinitive or 'plain' form, or a present or past participle.

In your example the subject is *hypocrisy*, which is 3rd person singular, and there are two verbs, whose plain forms are *do* and *make*. The first verb, *do*,  is inflected to agree with its 3d person singular subject, and the second takes its infinitive form:

> Hypocrisy ***does***n't make you a human.

Comment: But it's probably worth noting that in casual conversation native speakers often say things like *"That don't seem quite right"* (i.e. - informally many/most of us are at least *sometimes* quite prepared to use ***don't*** where it should really be ***doesn't***). Which don't bother me none, but obviously many will say it's just "sloppy" speech.

Comment: @FumbleFingers It ain't no skin offa my nose neither.

Comment: Losing skin offa your nose don't make you human either. I must admit I'm intrigued at the idea there's a culture somewhere on this earth using a language where the translated version of *Hypocrisy doesn't make you a human* would seem like a credible utterance. Personally, I'd have thought displaying hypocrisy would be better than any current Turing Test for deciding if the test subject was in fact human (if not, it would be unimaginably advanced AI! :)

Comment: Not *all* of us talk like that, though.  A lot of the English I use informally is non-standard, but I'd never say "that don't seem quite right".

Comment: @snailplane Some of us do it on purpose, to distress the people in marketing and PR who think the language they speak is English.